# Differentation w.r.t what?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I saw in a book that differentiated the volume of a cylinder $V= \pi r^2 l$ like this

\begin{align*}
V &= \pi r^2 l\\
\implies \ln(V) &= \ln\left(\pi r^2 l\right)\\
&= \ln(\pi)+\ln\left(r^2\right)+\ln(l)\\
&= \ln(\pi)+2\ln(r)+\ln(l)\\
\implies \frac{dV}{V} &= 0+2\frac{dr}{r}+\frac{dl}{l}
\end{align*}

where $r$ is the cross-sectional area of the cylinder's base and $l$ is the height of the cylinder.

At first it took the natural log of both sides and then differentiated it (I don't know with respect to whom) and then got this result.

Can someone please explain how is this done.

Comment: This would be so much easier to read (and more likely to get a positive response) if you used [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: As much as I want to help you MathJax it, it's, excuse my language, unreadable. Also somehow a $2x$ term pops up, which can't be correct. Mind telling us where you get this from?

Comment: I think that $x$ is maybe meant to be a $\times$?

Comment: This procedure is something that is done often and explained little: it's sort of simply "taking the differential of a variable", and isn't necessarily taken with respect *to* anything. It kind of says, well, *whatever* we *would* be differentiating with respect to, $d(f(u))$ had better equal $f'(u)du$. (It's clearer formally in differential geometry.) This is the gist; I'll leave it to someone answering to go into more detail! (But of course feel free to ask for clarification on what I've said!)

Comment: You should read about partial derivatives and total derivatives. For two variables if $u=f(x, y) $ then $du=f_x\, dx+f_y\, dy$. Apply the same to $V=\pi r^2l$.